# Windows: Preventing sleep mode - minimal version in C

Tags: c, windows, dev-c++

I want to have the most simple version of a C program under Windows which prevents the OS from entering sleep mode or hibernate mode while running. Currently I have this:

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    while (1)
    {
        SetThreadExecutionState(ES_CONTINUOUS | ES_SYSTEM_REQUIRED);
        Sleep(300*1000); /* wait 300 seconds */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, this isn't working - if I try to compile this with Orwell Dev-C++ 5.2.0.3, I get this error:

[Linker error] C:\Users\bachmann\AppData\Local\Temp\ccD8l1tp.o:disable_sleep.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `SetThreadExecutionState' 
   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

So what's wrong? According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa373208%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this should work, I think.

Comment: Well, what does it say in the 'windows.h' file for 'SetThreadExecutionState'?

Answer (score 2):

That is a linker error: you need to link with `kernel32.lib`. From the page linked in the question:

```
Requirements

Minimum supported client|Windows XP
Minimum supported server|Windows Server 2003
Header|Winbase.h (include Windows.h)
Library|Kernel32.lib                          <---------
DLL|Kernel32.dll
```

Comment: I added the kernel32.lib (from the Windows SDK) in Dev-C++ under Project Options, Parameters, Linker. However, this doesn't seem to be enough:


    [Linker error] main.o:main.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `SetThreadExecutionState' 
    collect2: ld returned 1 exit status 
    C:\Users\bachmann\Desktop\dev-c++\Makefile.win [Error] [NoSleep.exe] Error 1 (if this is the only error: please check your library includes)

Comment: @André, I don't use IDEs so I am unsure if the change you have made is correct. But `SetThreadExecutionState()` is _definitely_ implemented in kernel32.